# Completely erase all traces of database schema for practice in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am not new to Android or Java but very new to Databases. I have been practicing with SQLite in Android and have now become completely stuck.

I want to completely remove the current database that I have been using in my app and create a new one with more columns, different types of columns, and etc...

I have tried "context.deleteDatabase()" which appears to delete the database but then after that I uninstall the app and re-install it with the myDatabaseHandler java class file having all the new columns and changed added to the file. 
The code compiles and runs fine until I try to add info to the database, I receive an error cannot find columns, the error refers specifically to the columns that I added.

Why does it seem that I cannot start over completely. It seems like the structure or schema of the database won't change.

So how do I eliminate any evidence of the databases that I was practicing and messing around with, and just start completely new? After all, thats what practice is, you don't know what you are doing and you learn by making mistakes. So now I need to completely wipe away the mistakes, not upgrade just to make alterations.

Upgrading the database seems to provide an avenue for achieving close to what I want, but ultimately is way more involved and confusing for what I need when I just need to start over with a freshly created databases that has more columns.

Answer (score 1):

The `SQLiteOpenHelper` class goes to great care to keep the old database to allow you to upgrade it in place.

If you're not interested in the old data, just change the *file name*. Then it is guaranteed that there is no old version. (You still have to call [deleteDatabase()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteDatabase(java.lang.String)) to get rid of the old file, but now that call cannot conflict with any accesses to the new file.)

Comment: Ok thanks for your help CL. Now I did do both of those things that you suggested I do. In the past, changing the file name I know for sure would have worked, but I it's not working for me in this situation. Also what would help which I cannot seem to do is be able to look up the names of the databases on disk in my phone. I think I may have changed the names of the databases during my tinkering with them. If I were to "factory-reset" the phone, could you confirm whether or not that would at least allow me a clean slate? SQLiteOpenHelper cannot still be "helping" if I wipe the phone, correct?

Comment: Uninstalling the app will remove all its data.

Comment: I must be missing something here then because uninstalling the app is the first thing I did. But for some reason when I install the app again and run it, it won't accept any of the changes I made to the structure of the DB. The data is removed, but somehow Android still has a reference to this ghost DB that should be gone. It's like a Zombie DB that will not die. I also check how many DBs there are and I get 4 as the answer. My app only creates 2 DBs, I did change both of there names like a month ago. I cannot get the names of these DBs to even see what they are???

Answer (score 0):

Using the ADB tools from the SDK/platform-tools folder can help to remove all data (including the database schema)

./adb.exe -s  shell pm clear <your app's package name>

will remove all the data associated with your app. Then you install the new version of the app, it will use the new database schema.